# github api raw url how to get content

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, github-api

i want to know how to get content by using raw_url (`https://github.com/{...}/{...}/raw/{commit sha}/{path}`).

if I navigate to raw url, I can see the content in browser.
But I can't get the content using `restTemplate` in spring boot.

```java
restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, Map::class.java)
```

the 404 Not Found error occurs.

Note that I use Github API (`/repos/{owner}/{repo}/commits/{ref}`) to get commit files, so i can use `raw_url` and `blob_url`

Comment: Would [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65407692/6309) help?

Comment: thank you to ref. but it doesn't help.

Comment: i want to know commit files and get content from them using spring/kotlin

Comment: 404 could mean bad authentication: are you accessing a private repository?

Comment: i access private repository using token. so i can get well commit list.

now i can get data using contents_url!

Comment: When you [get the commit of a file](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/commits?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-commit), do you see the `raw_url` field in the JSON answer?

Comment: If the content is not open access, think about authentication

Comment: do you have an example of such URL returning 404?

Comment: i think only browser(like safari, chrome etc) can use raw_url to see content.
i guess in project, if i want to request using raw_url it can't read content.
so now i'm using contents_url to read content in project! now it works well!
thanks to comment everyone!